# SQL 2008R2 is taking 800MB of my server's RAM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-r2, ram

Lately i was experiencing heavy RAM consumption on server and after finding out which app is using the most it showed **sqlservr.exe** is taking **890,016KB**.

I want to know why does SQL take up so much of my server's RAM. My SQL performs simple functions on tables, store procedures and function and no jobs are assigned on the background.

I even tried restarting the server and after the restart when the SQL service started it took 90MB and after 8-9 users connected it the usage went back to 800-900MB.

**Server :** Windows Server 2008R2 Standard
**SQL :** SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Open SSMS, connect to your local instance an right-click on your instance name->properties->memory and check Minimum and Maximum server memory.
By default it will take a huge amount of memory, reduce your max memory if needed.

Comment: will this limit the max memory at time when the SQL actually needs it?

Comment: @user3779606 well, yes. It wont fail, but it will probably access disk more often. Try with 500MB for example and check if performance deteriorates

Comment: @user3779606 Check this post from awesome Brent Ozar's Team: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/09/sysadmins-guide-microsoft-sql-server-memory/